# Auto suggest dropdown in titanium example?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am able to implement auto suggest drop down in jquery .Now I am implementing a same functionality in titanium but when i googled I don't found much in autosuggestion 
drop down in titanium .

can you suggest a way of autogestion.

Mean I have a array (element).When I click on textfield it show related element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code and modify as per your need. Here I Used array(searchArray) as data storage(You can replace it with database field or source whatever as per your requirement).

```
//Table view showing your autocomplete values
var tblvAutoComplete = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    width           : '100%',
    backgroundColor : '#EFEFEF',
    height          : 0,
    maxRowHeight    : 35,
    minRowHeight    : 35,
    allowSelection  : true
});
//Starts auto complete
txtAutoComplete.addEventListener('change', function(e){ 
    var pattern = e.source.value;
    var tempArray = PatternMatch(searchArray, pattern);
    CreateAutoCompleteList(tempArray);
});
//You got the required value and you clicks the word
tblvAutoComplete.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    txtAutoComplete.value = e.rowData.result; 
});

//Returns the array which contains a match with the pattern
function PatternMatch(arrayToSearch, pattern){
    var searchLen = pattern.length;
    arrayToSearch.sort();
    var tempArray = [];
    for(var index = 0, len = arrayToSearch.length; index< len; index++){
        if(arrayToSearch[index].substring(0,searchLen).toUpperCase() === pattern.toUpperCase()){
            tempArray.push(arrayToSearch[index]);
        }
    }
    return tempArray;
}
//setting the tableview values
function CreateAutoCompleteList(searchResults){
    var tableData = [];
    for(var index=0, len = searchResults.length; index < len; index++){

            var lblSearchResult = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                top            : 2,
                width          : '40%',
                height         : 34,
                left           : '5%',
                font           : { fontSize : 14 },
                color          : '#000000',
                text           : searchResults[index]
            });

            //Creating the table view row
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
               backgroundColor : 'transparent',
               focusable       : true,
               height          : 50,
               result          : searchResults[index]
            });

            row.add(lblSearchResult);
            tableData.push(row);
    }
    tblvAutoComplete.setData(tableData);
    tblvAutoComplete.height = tableData.length * 35;
}
```

This code worked for me in both ios and android. Hope your problems get resolved:D