# How to remove the orange border onfocus in Android using Titanium?

Tags: android, titanium, border, titanium-mobile

I been with this issue for hours now with no luck. My setup is simple: I have a `TableView` with a search bar which is called like this:

```
var tableviewMainProducts = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data : dataProducts,
    search : search,
    searchHidden : true,
    top : '0dp'
});
```

And the code for the `searchBar` is

```
var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
    barColor : '#CCC',
    showCancel : false,
    hintText : 'search'
});
```

The problem that I have is that when testing on Android I see an orange border around the `searchBar` which I am trying to remove with no luck.

It looks like there is a `backgroundFocusedColor` for Android but that is not working for me.

Any tip on how to remove that orange border will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not remove the border from Searchbar. What you can do is create a custom searchbar using textField. Create a view for search bar, create a textField and add it to the view. Then set the `backgroundColor` or `backgroundImage` for the texField.
[image]

Here is an example

```
var txtSearch = Ti.UI.createTextField({
   hintText : 'My hint text',
   width     : '75%',
   top   : '5%',
   backgroundColor : 'transparent'//or backgroundColor : 'white'
});
```

Hope it helped you

Comment: Hello Anand, thanks a lot. I am wondering with your approach how do I make this new TextField work as a SearchBar in the TableView? I simply call it in the search field? Thanks a lot!

Comment: To make text field as a search field, you have to search for the values in the change event of the text field. You can use the help of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629345/auto-suggest-dropdown-in-titanium-example/18632608#18632608 for the same